# Print receipts via Chrome's USB API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I wonder if it's possible to print receipts from Chrome via an USB connected printer. I've started to dig into, https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb and trying some of their functions.

I am able to connect to the device:

[image]

But when I try different functions, such as `openDevice`, it just gives me `...is not a function`. This might of course be because of the printer model, or the way I have written my code. Since I haven't found no actual tutorial out there, I've just swung it so far (hehe).My current code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  let button = document.getElementById("connect");
  button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let device;
    const VENDOR_ID = 0x1c8a;
    const PRODUCT_ID = 0x3a0e;

    try {
      device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({
        filters: [
          {
            vendorId: VENDOR_ID,
            productId: PRODUCT_ID
          }
        ]
      });
      await device.open();
      console.log("device", device)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // await device.close();
  });
});
```

My `manifest.json` looks like this:

```
{ "permissions": ["usb"] }
```

Any help and tips I can get is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It may be a dumb question, but are you using a chromebook?

Comment: @AndyFoster No, I am using a Macbook

Comment: You probably can't do what you're trying to do then. https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html

Comment: @AndyFoster Aren't they writing about chrome apps that are in their store? And not the actual chrome api?

Comment: It looks like you can get a list of USB devices, but to actually use one you have to specify the vendor id and product id in your permissions.  Besides that, in the caveats section it mentions that devices on OSX with HID profiles will not work.

Comment: Hey! whats the outcome of this? Did you ever managed to get this working?  Thanks in advance.